# Intermittent Flask / Flask-restful, GAE 'Object" not callable Type Error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I have written a very simple REST API using Flask and flask-restful on Google App Engine. The API is designed to be used to represent data about a charity fundraising event. In this case a bicycle ride.

Everything seems to be working except that I **intermittently** get the type error shown in the following stack trace from App Engine's logs:

```
Internal Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackertest/1.376935219653445037/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackertest/1.376935219653445037/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackertest/1.376935219653445037/lib/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 397, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackertest/1.376935219653445037/lib/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackertest/1.376935219653445037/lib/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 487, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackertest/1.376935219653445037/main.py", line 268, in post
    supersedes=d['Supersedes'])
TypeError: 'RiderStatus' object is not callable
```

The RiderStatus object is defined like so:

```
class RiderStatus(ndb.Model):
    """ Models a status for a Rider with rider_id, location, action, time_stamp
        status_id
    """

    rider_number = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    location = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    state = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    time_recorded = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    time_occurred = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    status_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    status_origin = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    supersedes = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
```

The code section called out in the log is the creation of a new RiderStatus object and looks like this:

```
for d in statuses:
            created_count += 1
            status = Models.RiderStatus(rider_number=d['RiderNumber'],
                                        location=d['Location'], state=d['State'], time_occurred=d['TimeStamp'],
                                        status_id=d['StatusId'], status_origin=d['StatusOrigin'],
                                        supersedes=d['Supersedes'])
            status.put()
return {"created":str(created_count)}, 201
```

I thought it was perhaps how I was initializing the object, although I understand the preceding is commonly used in Python, so I made an explicit constructor for the class and an initialization method. The class then looked like this:

```
class RiderStatus(ndb.Model):
    """ Models a status for a Rider with rider_id, location, action, time_stamp
        status_id
    """
    def __init__(self, rider_number=0, location='', state='', time_occurred=0, status_id='', status_origin='',
                 supersedes=''):
        super(RiderStatus, self).__init__()
        self.rider_number = rider_number
        self.location = location
        self.state = state
        self.time_occurred = time_occurred
        self.status_id = status_id
        self.status_origin = status_origin
        self.supersedes = supersedes

    rider_number = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    location = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    state = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    time_recorded = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    time_occurred = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    status_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    status_origin = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    supersedes = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, required=True)

    def make_rider_status(self, in_dict):
        self.rider_number = in_dict['RiderNumber']
        self.location = in_dict['Location']
        self.state = in_dict['State']
        self.time_occurred = in_dict['TimeStamp']
        self.status_id = in_dict['StatusId']
        self.status_origin = in_dict['StatusOrigin']
        self.supersedes = in_dict['Supersedes']
```

And the creation looked like this:

```
for d in statuses:
            created_count += 1
            status = Models.RiderStatus()
            status.make_rider_status(d)
            status.put()
return {"created":str(created_count)}, 201
```

And I get a similar error:

```
Internal Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackermain/1.377017814438367636/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackermain/1.377017814438367636/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackermain/1.377017814438367636/lib/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 397, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackermain/1.377017814438367636/lib/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackermain/1.377017814438367636/lib/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 487, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~agonytrackermain/1.377017814438367636/main.py", line 283, in post
    status = Models.RiderStatus()
TypeError: 'RiderStatus' object is not callable
```

I get this error probably about 50% of the time I POST to that API URL. The other 50% of the time it works fine. I get about the same failure rate running on my local box with the App Engine SDk and deployed to App Engine. However, I have not gotten it give the error when I have the debugger attached. By adding debug print calls I have determined that when it fails it fails on the first iteration through the for loop and that d is indeed a dict with the keys and values that I am trying to access.

I am very new to Python, Flask, and App Engine so I could definitely be missing something here, but I have read all the "Object not callable" posts I have found and I have not found anything that seemed to apply i.e. I am not missing part of the constructor, I have not reassigned the object to another type, and I have not overridden a base type ( that I have been able to find anyway ).

I do not know if this is a FLASK issue, a Python issue, a flask-restful issue, an App Engine issue, or a me issue so my next step is to redo the API using only Flask and see if it works more reliably. In the meantime any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds as if you have assigned an instance to `Models.RiderStatus`; e.g. *elsewhere* in your code you end up doing `Models.RiderStatus = Models.RiderStatus()`, directly or indirectly. From there on out *that process* is broken and will continue to throw that exception.

Comment: Could this possibly be the issue? This is defined in the same class as the URL that most often fails:
`def get(self, rider_id):
         statuses = Models.RiderStatus.last_status(rider_id).fetch()
        return jsonify({'statuses': [Models.RiderStatus.to_dict() for Models.RiderStatus in statuses]})`
I changed the last line to:
`return jsonify({'statuses': [s.to_dict() for s in statuses]})`

Comment: Yes, in Python 2 that most certainly can do it. The name `Model.RiderStatus` is not local to the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments above I found my answer after further considering what Martijn Pieters suggested. The answer is in the comments on the question but I thought I would make it more visible in the hope it can be useful to someone else.

I had created a list comprehension using the code:

```
def get(self, rider_id):          
    statuses = Models.RiderStatus.last_status(rider_id).fetch()
    return jsonify({'statuses': [Models.RiderStatus.to_dict() for Models.RiderStatus in
    statuses]})
```

My understanding of why that caused an issue follows: this pattern caused the assignment of an instance of the **class** Models.RiderStatus to the object named Models.RiderStatus. Subsequent calls to Models.RiderStatus then tried to access the instance as if it were the class causing a Type Error. The last line in the above should actually be something like:

```
return jsonify({'statuses': [s.to_dict() for s in statuses]})
```

Martijn's comment implies that the first pattern might be ok in Python 3 but is an error in Python 2. I understand there were widespread changes in how class objects were handled in Python 3 but I do not know enough to validate or expand on that comment.

The intermittent nature of the problem had to do with the order that the URIs were accessed in. With the "right" order the issue became more visible.

Thanks again to Martijn for pointing me in the right direction!